# Unexpected use of the instrumental case

Tags: творительный-падеж

In the following Russian sentence, why is "весёлым человеком" in the instrumental?

> Его отец был весёлым человеком.

Comment: Compare _the Internationale_:  Кто был **никем**, тот станет **всем**.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150393/discussion-on-question-by-mherzl-unexpected-use-of-the-instrumental-case); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.